Recently started a new concept called Interceptor in Angular 17, but I got the error while practice
I tried to implement the interceptor concept in my angular demo project but I'm getting error on httpInterceptor line 7 i.e
`export const httpInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {`

I'm new to angular, I started learning angular through YouTube, angular official website. I'm doing a Todo Management App project by watching a YouTube video. I encountered an error while practising the interceptor code, but the same code is working on the YouTube video.
In the YouTube video, they are using Angular version 16 and now I'm using Angular version 17 and I done change the code according.
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptorFn, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TokenService } from '../services/token.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export const httpInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const tokenService = inject(TokenService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  tokenService.isAuthenticated.subscribe({
    next: (value) => {
      if (value) {
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenService.getToken()}`,
          },
        });
      }
    },
  });

  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (e.status === 401) {
        tokenService.removeToken();
        return router.navigate(['']);
      }

      const error = e.error?.error?.message || e.statusText;
      return throwError(() => error);
    })
  );
}


This is the error message I'm getting:
Type '(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn) => Observable<boolean | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<...> | HttpUserEvent<...>>' is not assignable to type 'HttpInterceptorFn'.
  Type 'Observable<boolean | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<unknown> | HttpUserEvent<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>'.
    Type 'boolean | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<unknown> | HttpUserEvent<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<unknown>'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<unknown>'.


You should share the error you are getting, makes it easier for use to easily identify the problem.

@TibèreB. : Type '(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandlerFn) => Observable<boolean | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<...> | HttpUserEvent<...>>' is not assignable to type 'HttpInterceptorFn'.
Type 'Observable<boolean | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse | HttpUserEvent>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent>'.
Type 'boolean | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse | HttpUserEvent' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<unkn

The problem seems to come from returning the router.navigate() function when using the pipe operator :
router.navigate returns a boolean which changes the return type of the observable which you can't do as the HttpInterceptorFn as a precise return type.
This is fixable by just calling router.navigate instead of returning  its return value.
We can then return EMPTY to end the stream and complete the observable :
import {
  //...
  EMPTY,
  //...
} from 'rxjs';

return next(req).pipe(
  catchError((e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (e.status === 401) {
      tokenService.removeToken();
      router.navigate(['']);
      return EMPTY;
    }

    const error = e.error?.error?.message || e.statusText;
    return throwError(() => error);
  })
);


HttpInterceptorFn has the following type:
type HttpInterceptorFn = (req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn) => Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>;

The code in your interceptor has a couple of issues:

Invalid subscription to tokenService inside interceptorFn
Invalid logic for redirection
Invalid return type for interceptor function

See Interceptor guide on Youtube
Problem-1:
So you cannot do async operations in the interceptor function and expect them to execute in order. So when you listen/subscribe to isAuthenticated, that async operation is not gonna execute in order. So while your isAuthenticated status is fetched, interceptor is gonna continue with next(req) call and your call will not have token appended to it. It might work but it will introduce unpredictable behaviour in your app so what is the best solution for that? For such a case where you need to wait for 1st observable to complete before you continue, you can use map operators for that such that this piece of code would look like:
return tokenService.isAuthenticated
.pipe(
   switchMap((value) => {
      if (value) {
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenService.getToken()}`,
         }
       }
     }
     return next(req);
  })
)

So this would fix the first issue where your token is not being appended properly
Problem-2&3
For this issue you are returning the value of router.navigate() which is of Promise<boolean> but it's not valid for HttpInterceptorFn so if do a redirect and throw the error again, you can add the navigation logic without altering the response behaviour. It'd look like this
return tokenService.isAuthenticated
.pipe(
   switchMap((value) => {
      if (value) {
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenService.getToken()}`,
         }
       }
     }
     // IMP: DOING THIS WOULD FIX YOUR TYPE ERROR. FOR YOU ORIGINAL QUESTION
     return next(req);
  })
  catchError((e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (e.status === 401) {
        // This would do the navigation
        tokenService.removeToken();
        router.navigate(['']);
      }

      // 1. This would throw the same error again
      const error = e.error?.error?.message || e.statusText;
      return throwError(() => error);
      // 2. This would suppress the error for the subscribers which is not preferred method
      return EMPTY;
})
)

Hope that sums it up : )

Problem-2&3 Solution worked for me thank you @Yousaf Raza

You can use "any" type like below.
export const httpInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn
=> export const httpInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn | any

issue not resolve
